# Error LNK2019: Unresolved External Symbol with LevelDB

Tags: c++, symbols, lnk2019, leveldb

I'm trying to use LevelDB with C++, so I put all the headers from the include directory in my project like this:

[image: file listing]

I use [this code](https://github.com/dazfuller/LevelDB-Sample/blob/master/sample.cpp), but the compiler returns 3 LNK2019 errors:

[image: linker errors]

So I tried to add the .lib file in the link editor, but I'm still getting the error:

[image: editor]

EDIT : Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23882710/12207411)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Please post text (errors and code) as text, not images or links. Look carefully at error LNK1120: Library type x64 conflicts with target(?) type x86. Configure your project accordingly and see if that might help.

Comment: Configured to x64, the LNK4272 is solved, but not the LNK2019

Comment: I don't know how, but the problem is solved