# How to link OpenSSL libraries statically in VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, static, openssl

I would like to use [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) in a VC++ project. But i can not statically link the libraries. Let me first talk about how I did it.

1, Download [openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz](https://www.openssl.org/source/) and extract it to "d:\openssl\sources\openssl-1.1.1h"

2, Build OpenSSL in [Visual Studio 2019 Tools Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs)

[image]

[image]

After built successfully, i found 4 dirs in "d:\openssl\builds\openssl-1.1.1h-VC-WIN32"
[image: After built]

And there are two libraries in "d:\openssl\builds\openssl-1.1.1h-VC-WIN32\lib"
[image]

[image]

3, Create an empty VC++ project in VS2019
[image]

4, Add Program.cpp and add codes in Program.cpp
[image]

5, Add static libraries by according [How to add static libraries to a Visual studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882112/how-to-add-static-libraries-to-a-visual-studio-project)
[image]
[image]
[image]

6, Debug and then i met error
[image]

Why did it look for "libssl-1_1.dll"? I linked "libssl.lib" statically! I can not find the reason, please help me!

I met "fatal error LNK1120: 28 unresolved externals" if i configure it with "no-shared"

[image]

[image]

According to [Unresolved symbols when built statically for Visual Studio](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6635) this problem can be solved by add below codes

```
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

It can be solved according [Add dependencies for "ws2_32.lib" and "crypt32.lib"](https://docs.faircom.com/doc/visual_studio_cpp/78449.htm)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .lib files that are created in a default build are just stubs to call the dlls.

When building OpenSSL you need to specify that you want to build it for static linking.

Modify the "Configure" line that you used to add "no-shared" onto the end, e.g.

```
perl Configure --prefix=d:\your\prefix\here VC-WIN32 no-shared
```

Then you will need to rebuild OpenSSL:

```
nmake clean
nmake
nmake test
nmake install
```