# Visual Studio - How to resolve the LNK2019 error?

Tags: visual-studio

I am new to C and followed the steps in [Tensorflow in C](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c). I am able to compile and run using the below command,

```
gcc.exe -Iinclude -Llib test.c -ltensorflow -o test.exe
```

Now I want to try the same in Visual Studio and I am following the steps as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882112/how-to-add-static-libraries-to-a-visual-studio-project).

I have provided below items in the properties window,

```
Linker->General->Additional Library Directories as $(SolutionDir)\\lib;
Linker->Input->Additional Dependency as tensorflow.lib;
C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories as $(SolutionDir)\\include;
```

However I am still getting the link error,

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__TF_Version referenced in function _main   tf_lstm C:\test\tf\tf_lstm\Source.obj   1
```

Can someone support me here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities:

1. The compiler might not be able to even find `tensorflow.lib`   Double check your linker paths. You've said in your question that the root solution folder contains "tensorflow.lib".  Are you sure?   Look at the project's *Properties >> Linker >> Command Line* item.  There you can see the full, spelled-out directories that the linker will search.  Look at each  `/LIBPATH:` item and be sure that one of them actually contains "tensorflow.lib"
2. Are you sure that `tensorflow.lib` is the only link library you need?
3. A third possibility is that Visual Studio is assuming that the symbol in question is a C++ symbol when it's really a C symbol.

   When C++ compiles/links a function, it decorates the name with all sorts of weird characters indicating aspects that do not exist in C, like calling convention, const-ness of arguments, etc.  The characters it uses to decorate the name are things like '@' and others.  But the point is, the same function's name becomes ***different*** in C++ from what it would be in C, even with the same header-file prototype.

   If you are trying to use functions from a regular "C" DLL within a C++ program, the compiler will assume that they are C++ functions unless it sees `extern "C"` before the function prototype.  The end result is that the function is exported as

   You can put `extern "C"` individually before  each function protottype or in a block around many function prototypes.

Like this:

```
extern "C" void foo();
```

or

```
extern "C"
{
    void foo();
    void bar();
}
```

You can even have an include file that does this and then includes the tensorflow headers