# vs2019 meet LNK2001 while using external static library yaml-cpp.lib

Tags: c++, static-libraries, lnk2019, yaml-cpp

I built yaml-cpp staticly using vs2019 and got lib from path `yaml-cpp-master\build\Release\yaml-cpp.lib`, now I intend to add it to my own project, simple code follows:

```cpp
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("test.yaml");
    if (config["test1"]) {
        cout << config["test1"].as<string>() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've set my project properties following [How to add static libraries to a Visual studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882112/how-to-add-static-libraries-to-a-visual-studio-project),
but I meet LNK2001 error and C4251 warning when building:

```
LNK2001 "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl YAML::Node::Node(void)" (__imp_??0Node@YAML@@QEAA@XZ)
```

it seems the linker still wants dll...which is not my intention, is there any possible solutions?

Answer (score 3):

You need to `#define` [`YAML_CPP_STATIC_DEFINE`](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/cdf89fa3526645cac68ef798aea4b363e6335cd0/include/yaml-cpp/dll.h#L10) before you include any yaml-cpp files or in your project processor settings.

Comment: cool, I never had a thought on it... thank you for your answer!

Comment: I still have linker errors even after defining this. I defined it for yaml-cpp project which I build as a static library. I have several linker errors for some functions that I am using inside my classes. Mostly it's unresolved external symbol declspec(dllimport) stuff.

Comment: @ŽarkoTomičić I suggest you post a new question with a [mre] though the answer is probably in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: This worked for me, but where is this documented?  How is one supposed to know to do this without Googling and ending up here?

Comment: @Arrow_Raider it doesn't seem to be, you could always raise an issue or pull request on the yaml-cpp project to fix it. They probably just expect people to import their library via cmake which i assume will set this automatically