# unresolved external symbol when trying to use QString from static QT library

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am working on Windows and currently have a typical hello world project. I built a static version of the QT Library. I included the header files and libs and when creating a `QString` I get a couple of errors..

```
unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl QArrayData::deallocate(struct QArrayData*, unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64)" (?deallocate@QArrayData@@SAXPEAU1@K1@Z) referenced in function "public:static void __cdecl QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(struct QArrayData *)" (?deallocate@?$QTypedArrayData@G@@SAXPEAUQArrayData@@@Z)

unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QArrayData const * const QArrayData::shared_null" (?shared_null@QArrayData@@2QBU1@B)

2 unresolved externals
```

I ran `dumpbin /SYMBOLS Qt5Core.lib` and I see what I believe is the function it is referencing. I have also found it in the header file that is also included in my include directory. I am not sure what else I could do to fix this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "QtCore/qstring.h"

QString tmp;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) does not answer my question. This isn't a typical unresolved symbol question it is related to specific QT libraries.

Comment: Could you show the command you use to build your hello world program.

Comment: I built in visual studio by just select the build option. Building Debug X64.

Comment: Are you aware of anything else than the header which might be needed to use a library?

Comment: So what steps have you taken to include the library in your hello world build?

Comment: I mean you said you 'included the libs' but what does that actually mean?

Comment: I added the libs and include directories based on the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882112/how-to-add-static-libraries-to-a-visual-studio-project

Comment: `I built a static version of the QT Library` do you have commercial license? This is only case when you have rigth to use static Qt library.

Comment: @brotherman068 OK that seems correct. Based on that I would guess that you made some mistake in building the library, or Yunnosch's suggestion is correct. Sorry but it's not an easy problem to diagnose from a distance. The more information you can add to the question, the better chance that someone will be able to spot the error.

Comment: I followed this guide https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git... I cloned the 5.14 repository, updated the submodules and then ran this for the configure line ```configure.bat -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests``` once that was complete I ran ```jom module-qtcore```